# How to assign ID value to another field while creating new record using Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to assign createdBy field with id field i.e., user_id while creating new record.

Tried with below code:

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserName("test");
user.setUserRegisteredDate(CalendarUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
user.setCreatedBy(user.getUserId());//NOT NULL field
userRepository.save(user);
```

But failed to save since createdBy doesn't have any value i.e., NULL

How to assign ID value to another field while creating new record using Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: either validate the user so the user_id can not be zero.

Also curious to know why you want to do that by setting the same value in 2 fields?

Comment: @Alien in our application, user can be created from application code and database also. if created from database then createdBy value will be administrator user id. otherwise it will be user_id of that record. so user_id = created_by

Comment: will the users be created after login?if that is the case then set logged in userid to that field.

Comment: @Alien No. GUI will invoke user signup API once user provided the inputs.

Comment: Could you pleas add User class to question?

Answer (score 1):

First save the entity to db ,  repository save method returns saved entity and you can get id from saved entity.

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserName("test");
user.setUserRegisteredDate(CalendarUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
user.setCreatedBy(savedUser.getUserId());
userRepository.save(user);
```